# subprocess output while process is running to GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, stdout, tcpdump

I use tkinter as GUI.
I try to run this and while the command is processing I need to get the latest line of output from the command in a GUI, therefore I guess I need to try to get the latest line in an var...
If I get the latest output in an var I guess/hope I know how to bring it to the GUI.
So my question is how do I get the output from the lines below, this output by the way is printed in my Console, in an variable.
How is it possible to get while the process is progressing (cause it is an infinite process I think) maybe every second the last outputted line as an variable and therefore be able to process this correctly ??

Thank you very very much,

if you don't understand something, feel free to ask and point out what you think is misleading.
Im sorry im still learning englisch.

````
    "tcpdump",
    f"ether proto 0x888e and ether host {bssid.get()}",
    "-I",
    "-U",
    "-vvv",
    "-i",
    "en0",
    "-w",
    "../captures/" + randomName + "/handshake.cap"
]
cmdHandshakecapture = subprocess.Popen(
    ["sudo", "-S"] + command,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)
# Write the password to the subprocess's stdin.
cmdHandshakecapture.stdin.write((f"{sudo_password}\n").encode("utf-8"))
time.sleep(4.0)
os.system("sudo kill %s" % (cmdHandshakecapture.pid, ))```
````

Comment: You should be able to do `line = cmdHandshakecapture.stdout.readline()` in a loop.

Comment: If you need this to be managed in the background while the foreground thread continues to process the tkinter GUI loop... well, that's one of the advantages of doing work in threads. Make a thread be responsible for monitoring the output of tcpdump and then your main program doesn't have to.

Comment: that said, there are Python-native libraries for collecting pcap data that directly expose your packets as Python objects and let you filter natively; I wouldn't recommend calling tcpdump via the command line at all.